# Combining tab bar controllers and nav controllers

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode8

I'm just learning how tab bar controllers and nav controllers work together. I have the following storyboard but I've also experimented with nav controllers too but can't seem to make things work how I want:

[image]

I have added a segue between the table cell and the "detail view" view controller. However, the transition isn't what I want as it slides up from the bottom. I would like it to slide from right to left. I select "push" but it still slides from the bottom.

In addition, I would like the table view to have the tab bar (which it does) but I don't want the "detail view" to have a tab bar (or nav bar and status bar).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your architecture would be like :

TabBarController - NavigationController -TableViewController - DetailViewController

For hiding bottom tabbar on detail just set `hidesBottomBarOnPush = true`
on the instance of `DetailViewController`.Currently your `DetailViewController` is not pushing because there is no `NavigationController` to add them up in stack as you want.

```
self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true
UIApplication.shared.isStatusBarHidden = true
```

For hiding particulars as you queried.

Comment: This has been very helpful. Thanks